# Write a function that will swap two integers using refrences

Tags: c++, function, reference, swap, temp

This is a particularly strange question, but i'm attempting to write a function that swaps the values of two integers without using references or '&'. I don't see how this is even possible. Here's what I have so far.

```
    void swap (int a, int b)
    {

    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;

    }
```

This, normally would be the way that I would do it, but since the integers don't permanently change, I have no idea as to how I would do this without referencing. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You are passing by value. Meaning your swap function may swap inside but that will have no effect on the caller.

Comment: Pointers are *technically* references (in that they reference something), but not in the same way as using `void swap (int &a, int &b)` would be, are they acceptable?

Comment: What is the entire content of the request? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NickA unfortunately not

Comment: @JakeFromSteakFarm Then what is this actually for? I see no benefit in trying to do this when better methods are available

Comment: It is not possible with that signature.

Comment: @JakeFromSteakFarm You can change your signature to `void swap (std::reference_wrapper<int> a, std::reference_wrapper<int> b)` to avoid the `&` or a pointer.

Comment: @user0042 It makes even less sense if that is a solution...

Comment: @PasserBy Should work though :-P .

Comment: @user0042 just because a reference gets wrapped doesn't mean its not a reference :P

Comment: @user0042 Unless we're ampersand-golfing what is the point of it? lol

Comment: @miradulo I like the idea of golfing ampersands.

Comment: @miradulo None of course. Silly questions deserve silly answers, that's all :-) ...

Comment: @user0042 I was amused, I'll give you that :P

Comment: You can't write your function without references or pointers.  The compiler will pass *copies* of the variables to your function.  Your function will change the copies but not the original variables.

Answer (score -2):

You should correct the question title. It says “using references”. That’s the opposite of what you mean, apparently.

Assuming that:

- truly no references and pointers allowed, exluding any wrapper tricks
- a runtime swap is what you want – as opposed to compile time template trickery
- no classes, because that would trivial

I can think of one utterly horrible solution. Make your ints globals.

*ridiculous_swap.hpp*

```
#ifndef RIDICULOUS_SWAP_HPP
#define RIDICULOUS_SWAP_HPP

extern int first;
extern int second;

void swap_ints();

#endif // RIDICULOUS_SWAP_HPP
```

*ridiculous_swap.cpp*

```
int first = 0;
int second = 0;

void swap_ints()
{
    auto tmp = first;
    first = second;
    second = tmp;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "ridiculous_swap.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    first = 23;
    second = 42;
    std::cout << "first " << first << " second " << second << "\n";
    // prints: first 23 second 42

    swap_ints();
    std::cout << "first " << first << " second " << second << "\n";
    // prints: first 42 second 23
}
```

It’s not useful for anything, but it does swap two integers without using references or pointers.

Answer (score -2):

There is this old trick to swap two integer-like variables without using a temporary variable:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    a ^= b; 
    b ^= a; // b ^ (a ^b)  = a
    a ^= b; // (a ^ b) ^ a = b
}
```